# Add methods to base class c#

Tags: c#, class, generics, base-class

Is that possible to add methods to Base classes like List? or others?
I really need to add method to generic list class if it has MyClass type.
like this:
`List<MyClass>.FindCoolStuff()` or `List<MyClass>.SetValueByName()`

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but you can use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DoCoolStuff<T>(this List<T> collection)
    {
        // Do cool stuff
    }
}
```

From MSDN: In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method syntax.

```
var awesomeList = new List<string>();

var awesomestuff = awesomeList.DoCoolStuff();
```

Comment: C# is powerfull, its great!
Good example.

Answer (score 2):

While you cannot add methods to a class, you can give the illusion of doing so using extension methods ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). Note that these methods will only appear on instances of that class or interface, not on the type (like static methods).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict it to working only for MyClass, you can use the where keyword; so using the example above

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DoCoolStuff<T>(this List<T> collection) where T : MyClass
    {
        // Do cool stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same thing.